# Printf for string goes down a line unwillingly

Tags: c, printf

This is my program (school exercise, should be receiving a string from the user, change it and return the original and new string in a certain format):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 50

char switchChar(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) {
        c = c + 32;
    } else
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
        c = c - 32;
    }
    if ((c > '5') && (c <= '9')) {
        c = 56;
    }
    if ((c >= '0') && (c < '5')) {
        c = 48;
    }
    return c;
}

int main(void) {    
    char temp;
    int i = 0;

    char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    printf("Please enter a valid string\n");
    fgets(stringInput, 50, stdin);
    char newString[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];

    while ((i != MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1) && (stringInput[i] != '\0')) {
        temp = switchChar(stringInput[j]);
        newString[i] = temp;
        i++;
    }
    printf(  "\"%s\"", stringInput);
    printf("->");
    printf(  "\"%s\"", newString);

    return 0;
}
```

When running, the output goes down a line after the string and before the last `"` character, although it should all be printed in the same line.

I would appreciate any directions.

Comment: Why define the constant `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` if then you use `fgets(stringInput, 50, stdin);`???  Why not `fgets(stringInput, MAX_STRING_LENGTH, stdin);`?  Get used to use constants in your program, so if you have to change the value, you have to do it in one place only.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues in your code:

- `fgets()` reads and leaves the newline character at the end of the destination array if present and if enough space is available. For consistency with your algorithm, you should strip this newline. You can do this safely with `stringInput[strcspn(stringInput, "\n")] = '\0';` or use a little more code if you cannot use `<string.h>`. The presence of this newline character explains the observed undesirable behavior.
- You read a line with `fgets()`, but you pass a buffer size that might be incorrect: hard coded to `50` when the array size is `MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1`. With `MAX_STRING_LENGTH` defined as `50`, it is not a problem, but if you later change the definition of the macro, you might forget to update the size argument to `fgets()`.  Use `sizeof stringInput` for consistency
- you forget to set the null terminator in `newString`.  Testing the boundary value for `i` is not necessary as `stringInput` is null terminated within the array boundaries.
- in `switchChar()`, you should not hardcode character values from the ASCII charset: it reduces portability and most importantly, reduces readability.

Here is a corrected and simplified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH  50

char switchChar(char c) {
    if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) {
        c = c + ('a' - 'A');
    } else
    if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
        c = c - ('a' - 'A');
    } else
    if ((c > '5') && (c <= '9')) {
        c = '8';
    } else
    if ((c >= '0') && (c < '5')) {
        c = '0';
    }
    return c;
}

int main(void) {    
    char stringInput[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    char newString[MAX_STRING_LENGTH + 1];
    int c;

    printf("Please enter a valid string\n");

    if (fgets(stringInput, sizeof stringInput, stdin) != NULL) {
        // strip the newline character if present
        //stringInput[strcspn(stringInput, "\n")] = '\0';
        char *p;
        for (p = stringInput; *p != '\0' && *p != '\n'); p++)
            continue;
        *p = '\0';

        for (i = 0; stringInput[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            newString[i] = switchChar(stringInput[i]);
        }
        newString[i] = '\0';

        printf("\"%s\"", stringInput);
        printf("->");
        printf("\"%s\"", newString);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `fgets()` reads in the newline character as well if there's room in the buffer and it's stored in your `newString`.

You can remove it with:

```
 fgets(stringInput,50,stdin);
 stringInput[strcspn(stringInput, "\n")]  = 0; /* removes the trailing newline if any */
```

From [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after 
>   an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the
>   buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Comment: Does it make more sense to use fgets or scanf in this program? Also, I'm unable to use the string.h library at this exercise, so strcspn doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You requirements contain:

- get only one string
- no special processing for blank characters

In that case, `scanf` is probably more adapted than `fgets`, because the former will clean the input for any initial blank(space or tab) and stop before the first trailing blank (space, tab, cr or newline). Remark: as `scanf` stops before the first blank, the string cannot contains spaces or tab. If it is a problem, use `fgets`.

Just replace the line:

```
fgets(stringInput, 50, stdin);
```

with:

```
i = scanf("%50s", stringInput);
if (i != 1) {   /* always control input function return code */
     perror("Could not get input string");
     return 1;
}
```

If you prefere to use `fgets` for any reason, you should remove the (optional) trailing newline:

```
if (NULL == fgets(stringInput, 50, stdin)) { /* control input */
     perror("Could not get input string");
     return 1;
}
int l = strlen(stringInput);
if ((l > 0) && (stringInput[l - 1] == '\n')) { /* test for a trailing newline */
    stringInput[l - 1] = '\0';                 /* remove it if found */
}
```

Comment: `scanf` will read a single **word** instead of a line of input. Note also that `%50s` will read 50 up to characters where `fgets(stringInput, 50, stdin)` will stop at `49`. Luckily, the array size is `51`...

Comment: OP is not supposed to use `<string.h>`, so `strlen()` is out.

Comment: @chqrlie: That's why I first said that the requirement was a single string. Of course it does not work if the string is allowed to contain blank characters... And strlen is one of the functions of standard library that can easily rewritten in 3 lines of C: `int my_strlen(char *p) { int l = 0; while (*p++ != '\0') l++; return l;}` - for the size you are right it should be `fgets(stringInput, 51, stdin);` or better `fgets(stringInput, sizeof(inputString), stdin);`